# Mongo DB not connecting to NodeJS after Heroku deployment

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, heroku, deployment

I've a MERN app (Mongo Express React Node) that works locally, and connects to my MongoDB database, getting data.
The React front-end works after I deploy it to Heroku, but Nodejs won't connect to MongoDB on Heroku.
The environment variables like `MONGO_URI` stored as Heroku config variables, works perfectly fine, yet it just won't connect to my MongoDB.

The Heroku logs shows the error message: `DISCONNECTED FROM MONGO DB` from my server.js file.

How can I solve this?

server.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const path = require("path");
dotenv.config();

const authRouter = require("./routes/auth");
const blogRouter = require("./routes/blog");
const userRouter = require("./routes/user");

const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());

app.use("/api/auth", authRouter);
app.use("/api/user", userRouter);
app.use("/api/blog", blogRouter);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
    app.use(express.static("client/build"));
    app.get("*", (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "client", "build", "index.html"));
    });
}

const connect = () => {
    mongoose
        .connect(process.env.MONGO_URL,
            {useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useNewUrlParser: true})
        .then(() => {
            console.log("CONNECTED TO THE MONGO DB");
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
            mongoose.disconnect(() => {
                console.log("DISCONNECTED FROM MONGO DB");
            });
        })
};

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, () => {
    connect();
    console.log("MONGO_URL", process.env.MONGO_URL);
    console.log("PASSCODE", process.env.PASSCODE);
    console.log(`LISTENING ON PORT ${process.env.PORT}`);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your environment variable to connect to MongoDB database has to be `MONGO_URI`, not `MONGO_URL`.
Otherwise it won't work.